# browser-sync 404 (Not Found)

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

Dir with css:

> /media/folder/assets/css

Project 1 dir:

> /media/folder/proj/01

Project 2 dir:

> /media/folder/proj/02

In HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../folder/assets/css/file.css">
```

This is works.

But in gulp+browser-sync don't works (404).
How to set up browser-sync so that it looks for the files in the desired directory?
The absolute path also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
browserSync.init({                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    server:  [ '/media/folder/proj/01/', '/media/folder/assets/css/']
});
```